# Create React App behaving oddly loading environment variables

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, create-react-app

### What's happening

This is a TypeScript Node.js/React project. I'm using `axios@^0.21.1` as my HTTP client and my application is sending requests to an ill-formed URL (`http://localhost:3000/ĥttp://localhost:3333/path-to-resource`) for any api call. I expected requests would be made to `http://localhost:3333/path-to-resource`.

This URL is being loaded from a .env file at my project root folder, and I'm lead to believe this is a problem with `Create React App` loading .env variables because if I run the app with `REACT_APP_API_URL='http://localhost:3333' react-scripts start` instead of loading `REACT_APP_API_URL` from a .env file, everything works fine. Also, this problem doesn't happen on a staging environment (deployed on Netlify).

### What I've done to diagnose this so far

I'm hosting the React development server at `localhost:3000` and my Node.js server at `localhost:3333`. I get the same problem by building the app with `react-scripts build` and hosting locally with `serve -s build -l 4000`.

Here's one example of api call:

```
// RegisterPage/index.tsx

const RegisterPage: React.FC = () => {
  // ...
  const handleRegister = useCallback(
    (email, password) => {
      api
        .post(`/students/register`, {
          email,
          password,
        })
        .then(() => {
          signIn({ email, password });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // ...error handling
        });
    },
    [signIn],
  );

  return (
    {/* ... */}
    <CredentialsForm
      submitButtonLabel="register"
      onSubmit={handleRegister}
    />
    {/* ... */}
  );
};
```

I import `api` from:

```
// services/api.ts

const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  baseURL: apiUrl,
};

const api = axios.create(config);

export default api;
```

And `apiUrl` from a config file:

```
// config/api.ts

// REACT_APP_API_URL is being loaded from a .env file
export const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL || 'http://localhost:3333';
```

If I don't configure axios at all (by calling `axios.create()` without `config`) requests are made to `http://localhost:3000` (as expected, because that's where I'm hosting the React development server). What's confusing me here is that if I log `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` or `api.defaults.baseURL`, both are printed as `http://localhost:3333`.

Also, if I write `api.post('/students/register', { email, password }, { baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333' });` the request is made as expected: `POST http://localhost:3333/students/register`, but if I pass `{ baseURL: baseUrl }` as `AxiosRequestConfig` I get the original problem.

### What am I asking

As you can see I have a workaround for this, but I really don't know exactly what's happening and why. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you are able to log both the env var and the baseURL and they both come back as the correct string removes the possibility of this being due to CRApp env var loading. Do you have a "homepage" value defined in your package.json file?

Comment: @DeanJames no, I don't. Could that be the source of the problem? If so, how?

Comment: By default CRApp does not define a homepage value - I was only asking in the off chance one had been defined, as this value iirc is used to prefix urls with the base.

Comment: What is the error message in the browser stating? Simply failed request?

Comment: Also did you log the `api` object

Comment: @Snake_py request fails with response status 404 (Not Found), which makes sense given that its making a requesto to `localhost:3000`

Comment: can you add the log output of `api` to your question?